# Escape Characters for LDAP/ADSI string

Tags: powershell, ldap, escaping

Below's some code I knocked up to escape the account name to be used in creating an ADSI reference to an account (e.g. escaping `$sAmAccountName` before using in `[ADSI]"WinNT://$Domain/$sAmAccountName,user"`

```
function ConvertTo-LdapEscapedString {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$InputString
    )
    process {
        $InputString -replace '([,\\#+<>;"=])','\$1' -replace '(?<=^ *) ','\ ' -replace '(?= *$) ','\ '
    }
}
ConvertTo-LdapEscapedString '   this, is a demo\example #1 showing escaping of ,\#+<>;"= characters   '
```

This replaces the following characters with an escaped (i.e. prefixed with a forward-slash) version:

- ,
- \
- #
- +
- <
- >
- ;
- "
- =
- Leading Spaces
- Trailing Spaces

Questions that led me to post this here:

- Is there an existing function which could do this work that I should call instead of rolling my own?
- Have I covered off all characters?
- Have I made any other oversights?

Comment: ps. For this script in context, see: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JohnLBevan/2e459b02601b8cfda50ee33259de85bf/raw/cc2ec8589c56f560a5f9432a0fd03dcce2ba2fb6/AddAccountToLocalSecurityGroup.ps1